# Reaching parse server from https fails with ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parse-platform, backend, quasar-framework

I have a [parse server](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) connected with my [quasar](https://quasar.dev/) framework. I have some problems connecting to the server with https. Http works fine though.

Running http works without any problems:

**quasar.config.js**

```
// Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
devServer: {
  https: false,
  port: 8080,
  open: true, // opens browser window automatically
},
```

**boot/parse.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
let parse = require("parse");

parse.serverURL = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/parse";

parse.initialize(
  "mylogin","mypassword"
);

Vue.prototype.$parse = parse;
```

But as soon as I switch to https (by deploying my dev server using [mkcert](https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/), it fails:

**quasar.config.js**

```
// Full list of options: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/quasar-conf-js#Property%3A-devServer
devServer: {
  https: true,
  key: fs.readFileSync('./src/certificates/localkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./src/certificates/localcrt.pem'),

  port: 8080,
  open: true, // opens browser window automatically
},
```

**boot/parse.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
let parse = require("parse");

parse.serverURL = "https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/parse";

parse.initialize(
  "mylogin","mypassword"
);

Vue.prototype.$parse = parse;
```

With the errorcode:

> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
>
> Error: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: "Unable to connect to the Parse API"

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you set publicServerURL too and try with that ?

Comment: then I get ````has been blocked by CORS policy````

Comment: How is your Parse server set up?